# Ionic cordova-plugin-screen-orientation doesn't work anymore on Ios

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

I've got some trouble with the `screen orientation plugin` since I updated everything. I have already a running app where everything works fine. But since I update every plugin and the cordova and ionic environment to the latest version my screen orientation plugin doesn't work anymore.

`config.xml` configuration

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait"/>
```

installed plugins

```
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 1.4.0 "Screen Orientation"
org.adlotto.cordova.recheck-screen-orientation 0.1.0 "RecheckScreenOrientation"
```

cordova version `6.1.1`

ionic version `1.7.14`

Javascript code

```
// to lock screen in portrait mode
screen.lockOrientation('portrait-primary'); // it doesn't work neither with 'portrait'
...
// unlock orientation
screen.unlockOrientation();
```

screen is defined but the function calls have no effect. I don't know why it doesn't work anymore. I tried it with my Iphone 5 (ios 9.2.1) and different emulators.

With my android device everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with cordova screen orientation plugin. Its broken for cordova 6x versions in iOS. The issue is still open and work in progress. Please check this [link](https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/issues/96) for more info.As per the plugin author's comment, the issue fix is not yet merged but you can go git pull to test the same if you are interested. Hope it helps.

Comment: @SimonSchüpbach You are welcome. Lets hope the fix is made available ASAP. Happy coding

Comment: I'm still have the same problem. In iOS the plugin doesn't work.

Comment: @futbolsalas15 you can try out from this branch - https://github.com/tony--/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation#fix-ios-rotate-on-lock

Comment: @Gandhi thanks for your help, but after I checked the <meta> tah with Content Security Policy, and remove it and rewrite again, the plugin worked again.

Comment: Same problem here. I can lock the orientation, but can't unlock it.